# Extract all RAR-files from subfolders into their folder

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch, winrar

I have the following folder structure in Windows:

```
C:\test
    |
    \----1
    |    |
    |    \----one.rar
    |
    \----2
    |    |
    |    \----two.rar
    |
    \----3
    |    |
    |    \----three.rar
    |
    \----4
    |    |
    |    \----four.rar
    |
    \----5
         |
         \----five.rar
```

Inside `C:\test` there are five different folders. 
Each of them contains a rar file. 
I want to extract all of them via command line.

So my approach was the following: to run `rar.exe`
with parameters inside the `C:\test` folder:

```
rar x -r *
```

This gave me the result that
all files were extracted to `C:\test`:

```
C:\test
    |
    \----1    (folder)
    \----2    (folder)
    \----3    (folder)
    \----4    (folder)
    \----5    (folder)
    \----1.txt
    \----2.txt
    \----3.txt
    \----4.txt
    \----5.txt
```

But I want every file to be extracted inside the same folder as its associated rar file.  
For example, `1.txt` should be in `C:\test\1` and not in `C:\test`.

How can I do that?

Comment: take a look at ... [1] `Get-ChildItem` and its various parameters. [2] the properties of the resulting fileinfo objects - especially at `.FullName`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is the following line:

```
dir -Recurse | % {$_.FullName} | Split-Path | Get-Unique | % {cd $_ ; & rar x *.rar}
```

It is necassary to add the folder path "C:\Program Files\WinRAR" to the Windows path variable, otherwise the rar command won't be found. If your using the the 32Bit Version of winrar the folder path is: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Winrar".

If you don't want to add the path to the variables you have to run the following command:

```
dir -Recurse | % {$_.FullName} | Split-Path | Get-Unique | % {cd $_ ; & "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" x *.rar}
```

Comment: But it isn't. Dir doesn't extract RAR files.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1001747)

Comment: First of all, this clearly is an answer to the question.  I don’t know whether it’s right, but if it’s not right, then it’s a wrong answer, which ***is*** still an answer.  (What species is an orange cat? It’s a cat!)  Secondly, the author of this answer is the OP (the author of the question), so telling them to address a comment to themselves is not “nice”.

Comment: @music2myear of course `dir` does not extract rar files. The directory just get piped to the loops. Inside the second loop the rar.exe extracts (`x`-switch) every file in the actual directory that the rar.exe can handle. So to be more specific and just extract .rar files only I have to write `*.rar` instead of just `*`. I will add that to my answer.

Comment: Works fine, though I used 7-zip rather than rar.  Saved me a bit of Powershell experimentation

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Save full path to `Rar.exe`

**2.** Get all `*.rar` files and full path recursively

**3.** Run extraction using:

```all-ps1
Full\path\to\Rar.exe:        ⁄⁄ C:\Program Files (x86)\Winrar\Rar.exe
Rar extract command:         ⁄⁄ e
Overwrite (if need):         ⁄⁄ -o+ 
Full\path\to\1.rar:          ⁄⁄ $_.fullname 
Full\path\to\extraction:     ⁄⁄ $_.Directory

C:\Program Files (x86)\Winrar\Rar.exe e -o+ $_.fullname $_.Directory
C:\Program Files (x86)\Winrar\Rar.exe e -o+ C:\test\1\1.rar C:\test\1
C:\Program Files (x86)\Winrar\Rar.exe e -o+ C:\test\2\2.rar C:\test\2
C:\Program Files (x86)\Winrar\Rar.exe e -o+ C:\test\3\3.rar C:\test\3
C:\Program Files (x86)\Winrar\Rar.exe e -o+ C:\test\4\4.rar C:\test\4
C:\Program Files (x86)\Winrar\Rar.exe e -o+ C:\test\5\5.rar C:\test\5
```

For **`C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\Rar.exe`**

```all-ps1
ls -r C:\test *.rar | ? {& "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Winrar\rar.exe" e -0+ $_.fullname $_.Directory}
```

- Or...,

```all-ps1
$rar=(ls -r "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Winrar\rar.exe" -Filter rar.exe -Force -EA 0).fullname 
ls -r C:\test -filter *.rar | ? { & "$rar" e -o+ $_.fullname $_.Directory }
```

---

- For **`C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe`**

```all-ps1
ls -r C:\test *.rar | ? {& "${env:ProgramFiles}\Winrar\rar.exe" e -0+ $_.fullname $_.Directory}
```

- Or...,

```all-ps1
$rar=(ls -r $env:ProgramFiles -Filter rar.exe -Force -EA 0).fullname 
ls -r C:\test -filter *.rar | ? { & "$rar" e -o+ $_.fullname $_.Directory }
```